# How to scrape data from Java based webpage using Python requests and JSON?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python.

I'm trying to extract general info from this page: https://www.sunnxt.com/tamil-movie/detail/8168 like movie name, year, language which is displayed on main page.

I tried with this code with no success as complete html page is not generated.

```
url = 'https://www.sunnxt.com/telugu-movie/detail/31257'

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36',

}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'html.parser').prettify()
```

Comment: Usually when parts of a web page are not extracted by http requests, the missing content is loaded via javascript. I suggest you try selenium to automate your browser and extract the full html from there.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply sir. but is it not possinle to extract full html without selenium webdriver ? cause i was told that it is possible with json but have no idea how to do it with json.

Comment: In your browser, the page is loaded in the following steps: 1. http-request gets the base html, which contains javascript code (this is what `requests.get` gets) 2. your browser's web engine executes that javascript code, which loads the rest of the html (that's why you need some web engine). You can also look at the javascript code and try to understand where it gets the data from, that you want.

Comment: if selenium is the only way.. how to keep it headless sir? while doing the task i don't want either webdriver or browser to be visible

Comment: It is not the only way (as I said, you can also read the JS code and see where the data comes from). You can keep selenium headless by passing the appropriate option to the webdriver. See the documentation, google or stack overflow for details (I would also have to do that to answer the questions).

Answer (score 0):

There is a script element **in the source** of the page.
This element contains the data you are looking for.
All you have to do is to get the data from there.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
        {
            "@context": "https://schema.org",
            "@type": "VideoObject",
            "name" : "Yaaradi Nee Mohini",
            "description": "Vasu falls in love with Keerthi.When he expresses his feelings to her,she rejects him saying that her marriage has been fixed.Later,he learns that she is about to marry his close friend Cheenu. Vasu&#039;s father meets Keerthi to talk about his son, but she insults him in front of her coworkers. The very same night, Vasu&#039;s father dies and Vasu is all alone except for his close friends Cheenu and Ganesh.  Cheenu forces Vasu that he should come with him to native for his wedding with Keerthi. Will Vasu be able to hold himself together while Keerthi gets married to Cheenu?",
            "url": "https://www.sunnxt.com/tamil-movie/detail/8168",
            "embedUrl": "https://www.sunnxt.com/tamil-movie/detail/8168",
            "contentUrl": "https://www.sunnxt.com/tamil-movie/detail/8168",
            "uploadDate" : "2017-03-31T00:00:00.000Z",
            "image": ["/images/logo.png", "https://sund-images.sunnxt.com/8168/500x750_ccd804fa-f7df-4ddf-8be7-c7752ea75bf0.jpg"],
            "thumbnailUrl": "https://sund-images.sunnxt.com/8168/500x750_ccd804fa-f7df-4ddf-8be7-c7752ea75bf0.jpg",
            "duration":"P0DT2H38M0S",
            "requiresSubscription": {
                "@type": "MediaSubscription",
                "name": "SUNNXT guest user",
                "authenticator": {
                    "@type": "Organization",
                    "name": "SUNNXT"
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: how would you do it?